# Cannot find module './cart-product.component' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Tags: angular, module

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductListComponent } from './Product-list.component';
 import { ShoppingCartComponent } from './Shopping-cart.component';
 import {ProductComponent}  from './Product.component';
 import {CartProductComponent} from './Cart-product.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, ProductListComponent, ShoppingCartComponent, ProductComponent, CartProductComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am a creating a cart all my componets are running but its still give me hard time

Comment: maybe you have to write your imports in lowercase i.e. `from './cart-product.component';`

Answer (score -1):

Please verify your import paths, ( keep it relative, ex: ./ or ../ ).